# how to run a spec file with ruby without spec

Tags: ruby, rspec

How to run a spec file with ruby without spec?

How do I inherit the spec base class to the current ruby spec file?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need are the files required in the spec_helper.rb you should be able to call the specs with

`ruby -Ispec my_spec.rb #=> assuming you have a spec folder and there is a spec helper inside.`

Answer (score 0):

That's two questions.

1) "how to run a spec file with ruby without spec?"

either put

```
require "rubygems"
require "spec"
require "spec/autorun"
```

in the file, or run

```
ruby -rrubygems -rspec -rspec/autorun whatever_spec.rb
```

from the command line. But `spec` is easier.

2) "How do i inherit the spec base class to the current ruby spec file?"

Basically, you don't. RSpec is an internal DSL which means that it generates objects for you based on your `describe` and `it` blocks. These objects are instances of real classes (e.g. `Spec::Example::ExampleGroup`), but they're very complicated and magical and you shouldn't try to extend them unless you really know what you're doing. What are you trying to accomplish?